# Fill a grid with the same component dynimically . Is there an adapter to fill it?

Tags: c#, wpf, uiscrollview, grid, autofill

1- I have a main grid and a scrollviewer inside the main grid;

2-  I want to display something like a list of programs of a tvshow.

3- I used the  scrollviewer to allow the user to scroll down and up the list of tvshows I want to show.

4- Inside the scrollviewer there is another grid that I divided in many rows;

5- Inside of this grid there are many grids. Inside each grid there is a different program I want to show.

6- Each grid has an image, and three textblocks.

**this is the scrollviewer:**

```
<ScrollViewer 
                        Grid.Row="2" 
                        Grid.RowSpan="5" 
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
                        <Grid Name="grid_tv_programming1" Grid.Row="2">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="90"/>

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid Name="grid_tv_programming"
                          Grid.Row="0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Name="txtblock1"
                                   Text="06:00" 
                                   Foreground="#1A1F49"
                                   FontSize="25" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Image Name="image"
                               Source="/Imagens/SmallLogo.png" 
                               Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <TextBlock Name="txtBlock2"
                                   Text="Acorde e Recorde"
                                   Foreground="#1A1F49"
                                   FontSize="25"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Grid.Column="2"/>
                                <TextBlock Name="txtBlock3" 
                                   Text="Nome do Locutor"
                                   Foreground="#9B9B9B"
                                   FontSize="25"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                   Grid.Column="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
```

**I want for each grid inside the scroollviewer to have this configuration:**

```
                        <Grid Name="grid_tv_programming"
                      Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Name="txtblock2"
                               Text="06:00" 
                               Foreground="#1A1F49"
                               FontSize="25" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Image Name="image"
                           Source="/Imagens/SmallLogo.png" 
                           Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="txtblock"
                               Text="Acorde e Recorde"
                               Foreground="#1A1F49"
                               FontSize="25"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Column="2"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="txtBlock2" 
                               Text="Nome do Locutor"
                               Foreground="#9B9B9B"
                               FontSize="25"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                               Grid.Column="2"/>
                        </Grid>
```

So, I want to create the grids inside the scroolviewer dynimically because all the programs are different. This way, I would not have to call its images and textboxs separately for setting up them. My code would be huge!

Is there any adapter library to do this?

If I create an array of objects, how would I set up the content dynimically if they don't have names?

Comment: Have you looked into `ListBox` or `ItemsControl`? Use a `DataTemplate` to define how the items should look in the list, then set the `ItemsSource` of the control to a collection of objects representing the shows.